# Design Pattern For Persistence

Tags: c#, design-patterns

I am working on a project where I am wrestling with trying to move from one persistence pattern to another.

I've looked in *Patterns of Enterprise Application Architecture*, *Design Patterns*, and here at [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd569757.aspx#id0400008) MSDN article for help. Our current pattern is the Active Record pattern described in the MSDN article. As a first step in moving to a more modular code base we are trying to break out some of our business objects (aka tables) into multiple interfaces.

So for example, let's say I have a store application something like this:

```
public interface IContactInfo
{
    ...
}

public interface IBillingContactInfo: IContactInfo
{
    ...
}

public interface IShippingContactInfo: IContactInfo
{
    ...

}

public class Customer: IBillingContactInfo, IShippingContactInfo
{
    #region IBillingContactInfo Implementation
    ...
    #endregion

    #region IShippingContactInfo Implementation
    ...
    #endregion

    public void Load(int customerID);
    public void Save();
}
```

The Customer class represents a row in our Customer Table. Even though the Customer class is one row it actually implements two different interfaces: IBillingContactInfo, IShippingContactInfo.

Historically we didn't have those two interfaces we simply passed around the entire Customer object everywhere and made whatever changes we wanted to it and then saved it.

Here is where the problem comes in. Now that we have those two interfaces we may have a control that takes an IContactInfo, displays it to the user, and allows the user to correct it if it is wrong. Currently our IContactInfo interface doesn't implement any Save() to allow changes to it to persist.

Any suggestions on good design patterns to get around this limitation without a complete switch to other well known solutions? I don't really want to go through and add a Save() method to all my interfaces but it may be what I end up needing to do.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing the point.. but can't you just include the `Load` and `Save` methods in the `IContactInfo` interface?

Comment: Why does the control take an IContactInfo if it requires the ability to Save()? What about maybe creating a SavableContactInfo type that implements IContactInfo and then having the control take a SavableContactInfo object?

Comment: @SimonWhitehead I could include a Load and Save but having close to 100 tables that we might be factoring out into interfaces I wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something more obvious and better battle tested before I started down this path.

Comment: @itsme86 good thinking. You just triggered a thought for me when I was thinking about how to create a SavableContactInfo class. I guess any object that implements an IContactInfo will have its own persistence logic so really it might make the most sense to have a Save on the interface. There is a potential for multiple tables to implement an IContactInfo and each one would need its own save implementation back to the original table so I couldn't refactor the save functionality out into on concrete implementation very easily.

Comment: @MarkRucker You can go a step farther and have an ISave interface. Whatever implements the ISave interface can be persisted. The alternative is a number of Interfaces with a Save method. In my book that would violate the DRY principle.

Comment: @MarkRucker On a side note, passing around one model that does updates, creates, deletes is not optimal. As you are experiencing now, it's becoming a bit cumbersome as your system has organically grown. Take a look at CQRS. Specifically at the separation of queries (create, updates, delete, read). Each has it's own code path. At first it's a bit of over architecture, but it shines as the system grow.

Comment: @ChuckConway Thanks Chuck that is exactly the kind of input I was looking for. I'll go check out the pattern tomorrow and see if it works for us. A quick Google brought up a page from Martin Fowler on it so that is already promising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily add a `Save()` method constraint to the inherited interfaces by simply having `IContactInfo` implement an `IPersistable` interface, which mandates the `Save()` method.  So then anything that has `IContactInfo` also has `IPersistable`, and therefore must have `Save()`.  You can also do this with `ILoadable` and `Load(int ID)` - or, with more semantic correctness, `IRetrievable` and `Retrieve(int ID)`.

This completely depends on how you're using your `ContactInfo` objects though.  If this doesn't make sense with relation to your usage please leave a comment/update your question and I'll revisit my answer.

Comment: I agree we could have an `IPersistable` but we would have to add that to every Interface. In my example case how would it resolve which Save() to use? IBillContactInfo.Save() or IShippingContactInfo.Save()? I think I'd have to fall back to explicit interface implementation and I'm afraid that'd be a real pain though I suppose I kind of have to do that already with the two interfaces so it may be my best bet. I was hoping for a magic bullet I wasn't seeing :) Also this is just an example so don't get too hung up on it. The important gotchas are the interface-inheritance-naming-conflicts.

Comment: My suggestion was to add it to the base `IContactInfo` interface, which is then inherited by everything below it. As far as 'which version of it', it doesn't matter, you are simply fulfilling a contract set forth by `IPersistable` or whatever.  There are no 'versions' of anything to call.  You may be getting confused with class inheritance and overriding, which has its own semantics.

Answer (score 1):

How many different derivatives of `IContactInfo` do you plan to have?

Maybe I'm missing the point, but I think you would do better with a class called `ContactInfo` with a `BillTo` and a `ShipTo` instance in each `Customer`. Since your `IShippingContactInfo`  and `IBillingContactInfo` interfaces inherit from the same `IContactInfo` interface, your `Customer` class will satisfy both `IContactInfo` base interfaces with one set of fields. That would be a problem.

It's better to make those separate instances. Then, saving your `Customer` is much more straight-forward.

Are you planning on serialization for persistence or saving to a database or something else?

Using a concrete type for Customer and ContactInfo would definitely cover the first two.

(A flat file would work for your original setup, but I hope you aren't planning on that.)

<strike>I think it all comes down to how many derivatives of IContactInfo you expect to have. There is nothing wrong with a bit more topography in your graph. If that means one record with multiple portions (your example), or if that is a one-to-many relationship (my example), or if it is a many-to-many that lists the type (ShipTo, BillTo, etc.) in the join table. The many-to-many definitely reduces the relationships between Customer and the various ContactInfo types, but it creates overhead in application development for the scenarios when you want concrete relationships.</strike>

Comment: Thank you for the answer. We are persisting by saving to a database though you are right we could abstract this implementation away and use other things like caching and serialization. To simplify persistence we are using reflection to move database columns directly to properties and vice versa. Creating the multilayer objects would be preferable but would complicate our ORM strategy so we are using interfaces. Also, I don't see how concrete types would solve my problem any more than interfaces? Would you mind elaborating more because I'm missing it.

Comment: @MarkRucker, implementing two interfaces inheriting from the same interface will definitely create a problem when mapping an object to a table, and interfaces don't serialize. Also, while interfaces are valuable, they are not a substituion for a good class hierarchy.  If you are concerned about derivative types, don't be afraid to employ table-per-inheritance.